# print this query out put in json format to use in php webservices

Tags: php, json

i have written this query in php file to get data from database ,it is working fine and getting required data .
but how to print the retrieved data in json fromat for using web services

```
$query  = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM subjects ";
$query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
$query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
   $subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 print_r($subject);
```

what code has to be done please help me.

Comment: have a look at json_encode function http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried json_encode? Like:

```
$query  = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM subjects ";
$query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
$query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo json_encode($subject);
```

For more information you can check: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$query  = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM subjects ";
$query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
$query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($subject);
```